# Attempting to batch delete duplicate nodes using apoc.periodic.iterate. Server keeps timing out

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am attempting to batch delete duplicate nodes. However, I keep getting the error `Connection to server lost. Reconnecting...` The server seems to be disconnecting and then reconnecting. I am trying to deduplicate all node types `Post` with identical shared property `unique_post_id`. Any ideas on how to do this deduplication?

```
call apoc.periodic.iterate('
MATCH (p:Post)
WITH p.unique_post_id as id, collect(p) AS nodes 
WHERE size(nodes) >  1
FOREACH (p in tail(nodes) | DETACH DELETE p) ','', {batchSize:100000})
```

Comment: Have you tried using a smaller `batchSize`, say `10000`?

Comment: I lowered `batchSize` to 10000 and am getting the same error. What else might I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the procedure incorrectly. Your first argument to `apoc.periodic.iterate` should be a Cypher query that returns a stream of nodes to be deleted, and your second argument should be a query to detach delete those nodes.

Try this:

```
call apoc.periodic.iterate(
  'MATCH (p:Post)
   WITH p.unique_post_id as id, collect(p) AS nodes 
   WHERE size(nodes) > 1
   UNWIND tail(nodes) AS node
   RETURN node',
  'DETACH DELETE node',
  {batchSize:100000, iterateList:true})
```

If this still fails, try decreasing the `batchSize`.